# why does rep() behave inconsistently with this simple R example?

Tags: r, rep

I am building code to run and manage simulations of sampling events at sites that can be in one of three site cohorts. I use `rep()` to assign the cohort identifier (1,2, or 3) using the code below:

```
cohort <- rep(1:n.cohorts, n.sites)
```

I have put the key line first, although to reproduce my problem you need to run the following lines, which allocate a total number of sites between cohorts for presentation to the `rep()` call.

```
n.cohorts <- 3
s <- 10 # total available sites in this example

# different proportions of the total can be allocated to each cohort, for example 
prop.control <- 0.4 ; prop.int <- 0.4 ; prop.ref <- 1-(prop.int+prop.control)
n.control <- prop.control * s; n.int <- prop.int * s; n.ref <- prop.ref * s 
n.sites <- c(n.control, n.int, n.ref)
```

now, `n.sites` by itself returns

> [1] 4 4 2

so when I run my `cohort <- rep(1:n.cohorts, n.sites)` call again I expect `cohort` to be a list of 10 items, like this: `[1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3`.  What i *get*, however, is only 9:

```
> cohort
[1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3
```

If i run the same code where `n.sites` is defined directly like so: `n.sites <- c(4, 4, 2)`, I get the 10 items i expect. I have redone this several times to convince myself that under both scenarios `n.sites` by itself produces identical results.

Can anyone explain why this happens?  Many thanks in advance.

David

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is one of those arithmetical inaccuracy issues in R. The problem is here:

```
prop.ref <- 1-prop.int-prop.control
prop.ref*10
#[1] 2
floor(prop.ref*10)
#[1] 1
```

So r thinks that `prop.int+prop.control` are very slightly bigger than 0.8

You can fix it by

```
cohort <- rep(1:n.cohorts, ceiling(n.sites))
```

But you're right, it does seem like a SERIOUS bug **EDIT - sorry meant *SEEM* like a *serious***

Comment: I'd say you have nailed it. So glad I asked. After confirming your suggestion i ran `print(prop.ref, dig = 20)` and the answer is `0.19999999999999995559`!

Comment: It is NOT a bug. It is well documented behaviour. `rep` expects an `integer` argument, you supply a `numeric`. Conversion of `numeric` to `integer` will always truncate the fractional part up to the precision of the machine. Try `as.integer(1.99999999999999);1.99999999999999`. See the two results.

Comment: sorry @SimonO'Hanlon; you're right of course that it's well documented, I meant to capitalise SEEM and not SERIOUS. But for a lot of people the assignment issue is very unintuitive, i.e. `prop.control <- 0.4; print(prop.int, dig = 20); #[1] 0.4000000000000000222` which is more a numeric/numeric issue, no?

Comment: @Troy sure, agreed. But this is a tradeoff of using R which lets you do practically *anything*. When you get results you don't expect you gotta go back to the docs and check, check check everything. If you don't supply arguments that the function expects then undesirable behaviour could occur. The alternative is to start implementing some argument checking in functions, which occurs sporadically in *base* functions and could be better.

Comment: @SimonO'Hanlon Yes I agree

Comment: I am happy to accept the tradeoff, and I do (now) recall seeing a post about this on RBloggers sometime in the last 18 months or so. In case anyone else is interested, I made a few more observations that might interest relatively inexperienced useRs like me. 1) if you add two more 9s to @SimonO'Hanlon's example like this: `as.integer(1.9999999999999999);1.9999999999999999`, they both return `2`. I didn't expect that - so 15 decimal places is a threshold of some kind?